# python-barcode: All barcode images seem to be output as SVG. How to properly output as PNG?

Tags: python, python-barcode

Below is a simplistic example I put together to try to generate a PNG image of a barcode using python-barcode.    It seems to me that no matter how I generate the barcode it always generates as an SVG.  As far as I can tell this snippet follows the paradigm in the python-barcode usage guide.

When I run this and try to open the file in something like paint or any other image viewer I receive an error that this is not a valid PNG file.    If I manually modify the extension to be .svg, then the image opens making me suspect it is writing in SVG format.

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
    
    bc_type = 'Code39' 
    options = dict(module_width=0.5,module_height=6,quiet_zone=1.0,font_size=8,text_distance=1.5,background='white',foreground='black',center_text=true, format='PNG')    
    BC= barcode.get_barcode_class(bc_type)
    
    if bc_type == 'Code39':
        with open("barcode.png", "wb") as f:
            BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter, add_checksum=false).write(f)
    else:
        with open("barcode.png", "wb") as f:
            BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter).write(f)
```

I have also tried to write the file using the following command instead of using a file open and write:

```
#with open("barcode.png", "wb") as f:
#            BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter).write(f)

bc= BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter)
file = bc.save('barcode',options)
```

I have tried with and without the format option set (it's supposed to default to PNG)

Lastly one thing I noticed is that in all documents I've searched for around python-barcode shows that the call line to the ImageWriter should be written as follows:
`bc= BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter())` with open and closed parenthesis after the class

every time I have tried to execute this way I receive an error:

> 'NoneType' object is not callable
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "Python Script", line 19, in onProcess
> BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter())
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Any suggestions from the community on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure: you do have the `Pillow` library installed?

Comment: @AKX thank you for the suggestion.  I did have pillow installed but the main issue seemed to be I was on a much older version.  After upgrading I was able to move past this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please ensure that you have the latest version of the python-barcode library installed.And try `options` argument should be passed as a keyword argument to the write() method, not to the save() method. So you need to include `**options` when calling the write() method.

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

type = 'Code39'  # this will be a variable
options = dict(module_width=0.5, module_height=6, quiet_zone=1.0, font_size=8, text_distance=1.5, background='white', foreground='black', center_text=True, format='PNG')

BC = barcode.get_barcode_class(type)

if type == 'Code39':
    with open("barcode.png", "wb") as f:
        BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter()).write(f, **options)
else:
    with open("barcode.png", "wb") as f:
        BC('12345', writer=ImageWriter()).write(f, **options)
```

Comment: Thank you Ramziya, this helped me get over the hump.  I went and looked at the version of both Pillow and python-barcode and they were very old on this server.    I installed the latest and things are much happier.  With a few tweaks I have it working.    

One thing to note.  I didn't need to use the "**" operator to pass inthe options.   When I tried that I received an error: 
**write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'module_width'**
I removed the "**" and just used this line and it appears to be working:
`BC('$(Input)', writer=ImageWriter()).write(f, **options)`